# Formation of hydrogen atom by electron proton collision

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, scattering

Suppose we have an electron $e$ and a proton $p$ colliding to form a hydrogen atom that is the reaction
$e+p\rightarrow H + \gamma$  where $H$ is an hydrogen atom and $\gamma$ is some photon.

The scattering amplitude should be I think
$A=\langle \gamma , \psi |S|e,p\rangle$

Here $\psi$ is a Hydrogen bound state.

Is there any book or paper that treat this problem?

Comment: Much (most?) of the literature on this topic is likely addressable through the search term "radiative recombination".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - as long as one avoids all the semiconductor LED and laser literature...

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already mentioned, *radiative recombination* is one possible keyword to look for, provided that one restricts one's search to atoms.

Another place to look is *inelastic collisions* chapters, possibly even in basic QM textbooks. E.g., Landau&Livshits have a chapter on inelastic scattering, but I am not sure, whether they discuss exactly this problem. They however do discuss intra-atomic transitions while electron is scattered from the atom.

Yet another option is *X-ray* absorption. In the context of semiconductors it is definitely discussed in the texts on many-body physics, but those focus mainly on the subsequent restructuring of the Fermi sea, known as the *Andreson orthogonality catastrophe*.